# How to save curl output in gitlab variable?

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

For a project we would like to call an API and save the result of this curl in a variable.

The pipeline is built like this:

```
stages:
  - download

scan:
  stage: download
  image: ubuntu
  variables:
    TOKEN: 
  
  script:

    - apk add curl
    - apk add jq
    
    - TOKEN=$('curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"username\":\"$USER", \"password\":\"$PWD"}" https://example.org/api2/authenticate | jq .token ')
    #- echo $TOKEN
```

I got this error:

This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:scan:script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep.

The curl command (removed from the $(), but kept the single quotes to wrap the double quotes) works regularly and returns the string with the token inside. The only problem turns out to be encapsulating the result in a variable. What can be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Why _did_ you add single quotes? Those prevent the command from running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try instead of this

```
- TOKEN=$('curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"username\":\"$USER", \"password\":\"$PWD"}" https://example.org/api2/authenticate | jq .token ')
```

The following

```
- |
  TOKEN=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"username\":\"$USER\", \"password\":\"$PWD\"}" https://example.org/api2/authenticate | jq .token)
```

---

P.S.
I would suggest begin by running

```
- |
  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"username\":\"$USER\", \"password\":\"$PWD\"}" https://example.org/api2/authenticate
```

In order to debug the curl command output, before running jq

Comment: Super! Thank you, it works. can you explain me the reason?

Comment: If it indeed works please approve the answer to help future users, so they could more easily find the solution
I will also update the answer with an explanation